# How to convert datas in Swift from NSArray to Dictionary?

Tags: swift

I need convert NSArray to Dictionary, but don't know how can I do it.

After fetch request I have result in NSArray. This my request:

```
 var results: NSArray = []

func fetchUpdateAttendee() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Attendee")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "needUpdate != false")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    results = try! DBWorker.context.fetch(fetchRequest) as NSArray
    results.forEach { result in
        print(result)
    }
```

`var results: NSArray = []
print(results)` give me

```
<Attendee: 0x60c000097750> (entity: Attendee; id: 0x60c000422200 <x-coredata:///Attendee/t9E88E2EE-9258-4FAE-AF80-9B036838C6D631> ; data: {
address = "1411 E 31st St";
affiliation = "";
attendeeType = nil;
city = Aguanga;
degree = MD;
email = "";
fax = "";
firstName = Oliver1212;
fullStateLicense = "";
id = nil;
lastName = Aalami;
meeting = nil;
needUpdate = 1;
phone = "";
signature = nil;
signatureTimeStamp = nil;
specialty = Surgery;
state = CA;
stateLicense = "";
status = nil;
timeStamp = nil;
zip = 92536;
})
```

I need to put these datas to:  `let dic4Attendee: [String: Any] = [:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Core Data `NSManagedObject` subclass, so the code is supposed to be

```
var results = [Attendee]() 


func fetchUpdateAttendee() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Attendee>(entityName: "Attendee")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "needUpdate == TRUE")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {
        results = try DBWorker.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        results.forEach { result in
           print(result)
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

**never** use `NSArray` to represent an array of `NSManagedObject` subclass.

---

Add a property `dictionaryRepresentation` in the `Attendee` class and return the key value pairs you need for example

```
var dictionaryRepresentation : [String:Any] {
   return ["address" : address,
           "affiliation" : affiliation,
           "city" : city          
            // and so on
          ]
}
```

then map the array

```
let mappedArray = results.map{ $0.dictionaryRepresentation }
```

Comment: I edited my code below. Can you write what should I do in my code?

Comment: I updated the answer. You have to put the `dictionaryRepresentation` property in the `Attendee` class.